# ¿Por qué este código PHP no funciona correctamente?

Tags: php

Muy buenas a todos, sois mi última esperanza de saber que error comento antes de pegarme un tíro jajaja. La cuestión es que estoy realizando unas pruebas para una app y me encuentro en el dilema de que me gustaría tener un archivo "save.php" para realizar operaciones de insercción o edición sobre la base de datos, este archivo recibe por post el valor id vacío si no existe el registro en la tabla y con un valor concreto si se corresponde con algún registro para poder realizar la operación de edición. El código de este archivo 'save.php' es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    //Inicio de Sesión y Conexión a la BBDD

    session_start();
    include 'includes/connect.php';

    //Comprobación de que el parámetro se recibe

    if(isset($_POST['parámetro'])){
       echo "Parametro recíbido.";
       $id_parametro = $_POST['parámetro'];
       if(empty($id_parametro)){
          echo "El parámetro está vacío. Crearemos un nuevo registro.";

    //Hasta aquí funciona correctamente, el problema lo tengo en la ejecución del siguiente 'else'

       }else{

    //Supuestamente cuando entra aquí me devuelve la pantalla en blanco, no muestra el pantalla el siguiente 'echo'
          echo "El valor del parámetro coincide con un registro, se modificará la información de dicho registro.";
       }
    }
?>
```

Y este es mi problema, la no ejecuación de esta última parte del código. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a ver cual es el error que estoy cometiendo. Disculpad por como se ve el código aunque lo he indentado, la parte central la muestra toda seguida. Gracias anticipadas a todos por vuestro tiempo y ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No tienes que pegarte un tiro, todo tiene solución en la vida. Ahora bien, no se entiende bien qué es lo que te ocurre, ¿qué es lo que no funciona?. Para identar el código lo mejor es que, una vez pegado el trozo de código lo selecciones todo y con él seleccionado presiones sobre los símbolos **`{ }`**  en el panel superior. Así quedará perfecto. Como consejo, evita el uso de palabras acentuadas en variables y valores como este: `$_POST['parámetro']`

Comment: A simple vista diría que es un problema con la condición del primer if. Osea parece que en: if(isset($_POST['parámetro'])), no se cumple y salta lo de adentro; al no haber un else pues muestra la pantalla en blanco. Ayudaría un poco ver el código html y añadir algunos var_dump para ver el contenido de las variables durante la ejecución.

Comment: A.Cedano, gracias por los consejos para la edición de mis próximas dudas para Stack Overflow. El tema de las tildes en las variables y/o valores solo están en la consulta que os hago por error. En cuanto a lo que me comentas Cristhian Mayuri, el código html en ambos casos se trata de un formulario que envía el valor de un input type=hidden, vacío en caso de insertar un registro nuevo y en caso de editar ese registro el valor correspondería al id de dicho registro.

Comment: ¿Pero los dos primeros echo se muestran? ¿Cuando se carga esa página se muestra "Parámetro recibido"? y si no se recibe ningún parámetro ¿muestra el echo correspondiente a esa condición? Si los 2 primeros echo tampoco se muestran el error puede ser el que te ha dicho Christian, que la primera condición no se cumple; en cambio si los 2 primeros echo se muestran cuando se cumple la condición correspondiente el problema estaría en otra parte, ¿Si el parámetro está vacío no se muestra nada o se muestra el echo indicando que está vacío?

Comment: Gracias a todos, por vuestros comentarios que han sido de gran ayuda y me han ayudado a encontrar el problema (que resultaba estar en otro archivo). Gracias de nuevo.